# LIKE operator not working properly with date

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to return a record which contains the year of a date, let me explain better, this is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT coach.*
  FROM coach_career coach_cr
  LEFT JOIN coach coach ON coach.id = coach_cr.coach_id
  LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.id = :season_id
  WHERE coach_cr.team_id = 95 AND `start` LIKE '%2017/2018%'";
```

I need to select all the `coach` fields on `coach_career`, a `coach` can train different team in different `seasons`, so I need to take the coach that have as `season.name` the value `2017/2018`, but the `start` date have a datetime format like: 2017-01-01

How can I handle this situation?

**Sample Data**

coach:

```
id | name | last_name
 1   foo      test
```

coach_career:

```
coach_id | team_id | start       | end
   1         95       2017-01-01   NULL
```

competition_seasons

```
id | name | 
1    2017/2018
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff check my update

Comment: If `start` is a date then use `start >= '2017-01-01' AND start < '2019-01-01'`

Comment: @SalmanA the problem is not start field, the problem is s.name that is not a date and contains 2017/2018

Comment: If you use `'2017/2018' like '%' + convert(varchar(10), datepart(year, [start])) + '%'` instead of `[start] like '%2017/2018%'` will it solve your problem?

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk could you please write an answer, I have some problem to implement your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my answer was for SQL Server. Here is the corrected version:

```
create table coach(id integer, name char(100));
insert into coach(id, name) values(1, 'Jack'), (2, 'Peter');

create table coach_career (coach_id integer, season_id integer, start date, end date);
insert into coach_career values (1, 95, '20170101', null), (2, 95, '20010101', null);

create table competition_seasons (id integer, name char(100));
insert into competition_seasons values (95, '2017/2018');

SELECT coach.*
FROM coach_career cc
LEFT JOIN coach ON coach.id = cc.coach_id
LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.id = cc.season_id
WHERE cc.season_id = 95 
      AND '2017/2018' like concat('%', cast(extract(year from cc.start) as char(100)), '%');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately your query return an empty result...

Comment: That's strange, I tested it on https://paiza.io/projects/SdtzcJ0SoUfg1QS7k3I8QQ?language=mysql and it returns `Jack`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `BETWEEN` keyword.

```
$query = "SELECT coach.*
      FROM coach_career coach_cr
      LEFT JOIN coach coach ON coach.id = coach_cr.coach_id
      LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.id = :season_id
      WHERE coach_cr.team_id = 95 AND `start` BETWEEN '2017-01-01' and '2018-12-31'";
```

Comment: the value of `s.name` is `2017/2018%` as I wrote in query, so instead of `2017/2018%` think that is s.name, I cannot use between..

Comment: Could you use : ` WHERE coach_cr.team_id = 95 AND (s.name like '%2017%' OR s.name like '%2018%')`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$query = "SELECT coach.*
    FROM coach_career coach_cr
    LEFT JOIN coach coach 
        ON coach.id = coach_cr.coach_id
    LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s
        ON s.id = :season_id
    WHERE coach_cr.team_id = 95 
        AND `start` LIKE '%2017%' 
        OR LIKE '%2018%'";
```